# Изменить порядок объектов

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли изменить порядок объектов через скрипт? Пример на скриншоте. Или есть возможность добавлять объект (тоже через скрипт) не в конец списка, а в начало?
[image: scr]

Comment: Я заметил, что порядок объектов на Canvas зависит от положения в очереди. Чтобы объект был на переднем плане, он должен быть выше

Comment: Во... важное уточнение, что нужно это для UI (желательно это было в вопросе и указать, что конкретно это интересует). Если никто не ответит - постараюсь завтра написать

Answer (score 0):

Нужно использовать следующий метод

```
gameobject.transform.SetAsFirstSibling();
```